# с установкой xcode 9 проблема

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

После установки нового xcode 9(и получается в swift 4)в этом фрагменте кода вылетает fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Есть любые идеи?

```
private func setNeedsDisplay(page: Int) {
        if (0 ..< numberOfPages).contains(page) {
            let (_, _, rect) = paths[page]
            setNeedsDisplay(rect)
        }
    }
```

numberOfPages:

```
var numberOfPages: NSInteger = 0 {
        didSet {
            if numberOfPages < 0 {
                numberOfPages = 0
            } else {
                paths = nil
                setNeedsDisplay()
                invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
            }
        }
    }
```

paths[page]:

```
private lazy var paths: [(UIBezierPath, UIBezierPath, CGRect)]! = {
        [unowned self] in
        let halfLineWidth = Constants.lineWidth / 2
        var result = [(UIBezierPath, UIBezierPath, CGRect)]()
        for i in 0 ..< self.numberOfPages {
            let currentDotBounds = CGRect(x: (Constants.dotSize + Constants.spacing) * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: Constants.dotSize, height: Constants.dotSize)

            let outlinePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: currentDotBounds.insetBy(dx: halfLineWidth, dy: halfLineWidth), cornerRadius: Constants.cornerRadius)
            outlinePath.lineWidth = Constants.lineWidth

            let fillPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: currentDotBounds, cornerRadius: Constants.cornerRadius + Constants.lineWidth / 2)

            result.append(outlinePath, fillPath, currentDotBounds)
        }
        return result
    }()
```

Comment: Интересная взаимосвязь. Покажите свои numberOfPages и paths[page]

Comment: Действительно интересная. Я добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, в строке `let (_, _, rect) = paths[page]` содержатся опционалы.

Попробуйте использовать следующий код:

```
private func setNeedsDisplay(page: Int) {
        if (0 ..< numberOfPages).contains(page) {
            guard let (_, _, rect) = paths[page] else {
                print("something is wrong here")
                return
            }   
            setNeedsDisplay(rect)
        }
    }
```

Update:
Приглядитесь, если вы установите `numberOfSet` равным или больше нуля (ветка `else`), то переменной paths будет установлено значение `nil`. Затем, в `setNeedsDisplay` внутри цикла вы пытаетесь вытащить из `paths` значение по индексу и получаете закономерную ошибку. Соответственно, в `guard` нужно вытащить объект `paths`. Попробуйте следующий код:

```
private func setNeedsDisplay(page: Int) {
        guard let paths = paths else {
            print("something is wrong here")
            return
        }
        if (0 ..< numberOfPages).contains(page) {
            let (_, _, rect) = paths[page] else { 
            setNeedsDisplay(rect)
        }
    }
```

Comment: увы не компилируется с такой ошибкой: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '(UIBezierPath, UIBezierPath, CGRect)'

Comment: Я обновил свой комменатрий